# What does "that's saying something" mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, idioms

> “You know how I think they choose people for the Gryffindor team?”
>   said Malfoy loudly a few minutes later, as Snape awarded Hufflepuff
>   another penalty for no reason at all. “It’s people they feel sorry
>   for. See, there’s Potter, who’s got no parents, then there’s the
>   Weasleys, who’ve got no money — you should be on the team, Longbottom,
>   you’ve got no brains.” 
>  Neville went bright red but turned in his
>   seat to face Malfoy. 
>  “I’m worth twelve of you, Malfoy,” he
>   stammered. 
>  Malfoy, Crabbe, and Goyle howled with laughter, but
>   Ron, still not daring to take his eyes from the game, said, “You tell
>   him, Neville.” 
>  “Longbottom, if brains were gold you’d be poorer
>   than Weasley, and **that’s saying something**.” 
>  Ron’s nerves
>   were already stretched to the breaking point with anxiety about Harry.
>   “I’m warning you, Malfoy — one more word—”
>
> “How did I get the Stone out of the mirror?” 
>  “Ah, now, I’m glad
>   you asked me that. It was one of my more brilliant ideas, and between
>   you and me, **that’s saying something**. You see, only one who
>   wanted to find the Stone — find it, but not use it — would be able to
>   get it, otherwise they’d just see themselves making gold or drinking
>   Elixir of Life. My brain surprises even me sometimes… Now, enough
>   questions. I suggest you make a start on these sweets. Ah! Bettie
>   Bott’s Every Flavor Beans! I was unfortunate enough in my youth to
>   come across a vomit flavored one, and since then I’m afraid I’ve
>   rather lost my liking for them — but I think I’ll be safe with a nice
>   toffee, don’t you?” 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Does "that's saying something" have the same meaning shown on [macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/something#that-s-saying-something) ("used for emphasizing that what you have said is more extreme than it seems")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, it does have the same meaning that you describe.

> “Longbottom, if brains were gold you’d be poorer than Weasley, and that’s saying something.”

Weasley is very poor, and so if Longbottom's brains were gold, he would be incredibly poor.

> It was one of my more brilliant ideas, and between you and me, that’s saying something.

The speaker has a lot of brilliant ideas, and so for the current idea to be "more brilliant", it must be extremely brilliant.